# Drawing overlay realtime using GPUImage (iOS)

Tags: ios, overlay, real-time, video-processing, gpuimage

Is it possible with GPUImage to capture video, display it in black and white, and at the same draw over the video a result depending on the video images (say feature extraction) but in color, for example drawing red squares over a B&W video? How could we achieve this easily? Any hint would greatly help!

Thank you!
Diego

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! You can do the first part easily, by refering to the examples that Brad provides with the GPUImage framework.

For the feature detection, you will need to convert the frame to an CIImage to use CIDetector, but better, write your own AVCapture code and use AVMetaDataOutput to do the feature detection.

For drawing red sqaures, GPUImage can do that easily but you might want to create your own filter.